# Table column conditional js formatting

Tags: javascript, html-table, formatting, conditional-statements

I have an HTML table formatted with CSS.

I want the cells of the **4th column** to have a red background if their value is smaller than -2 and green background if greater than +2.

Please advise.

Comment: Please provide the code blocks related to this question especially the HTML code of the table and the JS part of the code if there is any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below script will work for your requirement, [HERE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdwJGz)  is a working example for your reference.
if you have multiple tables just give it a class and amend the script as required.

```
var trTags = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (var i = 0; i < trTags.length; i++) {
  var tdFourthEl = trTags[i].children[3]; // starts with 0, so 3 is the 4th element
  if (tdFourthEl.innerText < -2) {
    tdFourthEl.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  } else if (tdFourthEl.innerText > 2) {
    tdFourthEl.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.. Change the value in the fourth row to change background colour.

```js
    (function(){
        var valueOfFourthRowValue = document.getElementById("value");
        if (valueOfFourthRowValue.textContent > 2) {
            valueOfFourthRowValue.style.backgroundColor = "green"
        } else if (valueOfFourthRowValue.textContent < -2) {
            valueOfFourthRowValue.style.backgroundColor = "red"
        }

    })()
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><td>One Row</td></tr>
    <tr><td>One Row</td></tr>
    <tr><td>One Row</td></tr>
    <tr><td id="value">3</td></tr>
</table>
```

if the table is dynamic and you want to grab the last element then use xpath.

```
var tableColumn = document.evaluate('//table//tr[last()]/td', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext();
tableColumn.setAttribute("id", "value");
```

Comment: Thanks but I need it for a specific column

Comment: just add the id="value" to what ever column (td element) you need it on. If the table is dynamic then use xpath to insert the ID.